# How can I repackage a website as a WP8 app?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, web, mobile-website

I want to do a very basic repackage of a website as a WP8 app, similar to how [Microsoft has done it here](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/store/publishers?publisherId=Microsoft%2bWebApps).

What kind of project do I create in Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone? And what is the general strategy for developing this kind of app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select "Windows Phone HTML5 App" template. It basically uses `WebBrowser` control to open the website. Template also has application bar with back, forward & refresh button.

When you create the app, go to `MainPage.xaml.cs` and change `MainUri` string to website's name and use `UriKind` as `UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute` in `Browser_Loaded` event.

[image]